# IAM Policy for S3 folder access for group of Cognito IDs

Tags: mobile, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, amazon-cognito

I'd like to share individual s3 folders between groups of cognito users, identifying with assume_role_with_web_identity, e.g.

**group A**: Device 1, Device 2

**group B**: Device 4, Device5, Device 10, ..., Device 23

group A has a shared folder: mybucket/groupA/*, and cannot access group B's folder.

group B has a shared folder: mybycket/groupB/*, and cannot access group A's folder.

We can expect 1000 groups.

As far as I can see from examples on the web, it is only possible to specify device-only ID's in a shared policy, using something like this:

    `"Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/*"
    ]`

But I am at a loss for how to grant access to groups of devices with a shared policy. Please help.

NB! Amazon has a role limit at 250 roles per account, so I cannot create a role per group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon Cognito does not support groups.  Cognito credentials can not be used to access another identity or groups assets at this time.  Cognito credentials can either be used to access the identity's assets or global assets.

[This blog post](http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx1OSMBRHZVM9V0/Understanding-Amazon-Cognito-Authentication-Part-3-Roles-and-Policies) shows examples of using conditional policies to give additional users access, but unfortunately this would not scale to 1000s of groups.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. Do you know if there is any way we can use regular amazon access to achieve this goal, and we just skip cognito as mobile access gateway for the time being? I was also considering if it's possible to use security through obscurity so users have read access to objects in a known bucket/folder, but cannot list the objects if they don't know the folder name in advance.

Comment: @user681814 As the IAM policy will still be used in the direct Amazon method, bypassing Cognito does not solve the issue.

Comment: Amazon Cognito does support groups